# Setting multiple variables from one pandas dataframe.loc request

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask, query-optimization

I'm writing a web app for the end of year laptop return to make our lives easier. I have a .csv file containing device serial numbers and the associated user's first and last name, user code, ...etc. I am using flask as the frame work and all is going well. I can use pandas to create the dataframe and lookup all the info I need, however, it is either make a new dataframe with just one user's details which means I have to then pull information out of that again or I set each variable I need by running the dataframe.loc query on the full table 5 times which to me seems really inefficient.

What I want to do is run the .loc query once and set the multiple variables to the values of the corresponding cells of the returned row. I have searched all over but I can't find a method of doing so but perhaps my google-fu is not as good as I thought.

I know that this is probably something I should change in a later step when I adjust efficiency and right now just focus on getting it working, but this seems like a big hole when 5 queries could be handled with 1.

here is my current code (it only grabs first and last name, but I will have to get more information later).

```
`@app.route('/lookup', methods=['GET','POST'])
def lookup():
    st = request.form['serviceTag'] if 'serviceTag' in request.form else None
    fName = df.loc[st]['fName']
    sName = df.loc[st]['sName']
    return {
        'fname': fName,
        'sname': sName
    }`
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply provide a list of columns to `loc` and then use `to_dict` on the result:

```py
def lookup():
    cols = ['fname', 'sname']    # add more as desired
    st = request.form['serviceTag'] if 'serviceTag' in request.form else None
    return df.loc[st, cols].to_dict()
```

Note that if `st` is `None` this will raise a KeyError, in that scenario you may want to return `None` instead. e.g.

```
def lookup():
    cols = ['fname', 'sname']    # add more as desired
    if not 'serviceTag' in request.form:
        return None
    st = request.form['serviceTag']
    return df.loc[st, cols].to_dict()
```

Comment: Yup, that'll do it! Thanks so much Nick. I knew it was going to be a simple answer. I just wasn't thinking in the right "frame" of mind. Ha Ha Ha... I'm sorry.

Comment: @Scobbo I'm glad I could help. But did you have to add the bad pun????? :-P